# c++ graphics.h text on top of a colored rectangle

Tags: c++, bgi

I am working with the graphics.h header and got 3 problems.

1. I tried to change the Name of the window to Simple Pong, as you can see in line 8, but it still tells me Windows BGI.
2. I have a text on top of a colored rectangle, but inside of an O is no color, how can I fix that.
3. About the text again, when I do not put `floodfill` (line 27) then the text is inside a white rectangle, but if I put `floodfill` the text gets really thin.

Here is my output:

[image: output]

Thats my code:

```
#include<graphics.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>


main()
{
    initwindow(640,480,"Simple Pong");

    setbkcolor(15);
    setfillstyle(SOLID_FILL,15);
    floodfill(1,1,15);

    setcolor(BLACK);
    rectangle(27,17,603,123);
    setfillstyle(SOLID_FILL,BLACK);
    floodfill(41,41,BLACK);

    setcolor(YELLOW);
    rectangle(30,20,600,120);
    setfillstyle(SOLID_FILL,YELLOW);
    floodfill(41,41,YELLOW);

    setcolor(BLACK);
    settextstyle(8, 0, 7);
    outtextxy(130,35,"SIMPLE PONG");
    floodfill(185,47,BLACK);

    getch();
}
```

Comment: I am not familiar with this graphics library, but can you do the yellow flood-fill first, then render the text on top? Does `getch()` do the rendering?

Comment: Hey there! The graphics.h header that you are using is ancient and you won't find many people to help you with it nowadays. You should definitely give a library called [SDL](http://www.lazyfoo.net/SDL_tutorials/) a try. I believe the equivalent functions are called `SDL_CreateWindow`, `SDL_FillRect` and `SDL_WM_SetCaption` (to set the caption as you want), and there will be many more resources to help you with any questions.